# How to model ball joint in Patran/Nastran?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, modeling, simulation

I would like to model below mechanical system in Patran.

[image]

But, I don't know how to configure boundary condition of ball joint.

The ball joint is spherically rotated.

When the described system is in gravity, the upper beam and supports would be deformed, then contact point of ball joint would be slightly rotated.

In my model, I just rigidly connected the ball joint by using RBE 2.

But, with my model, I can not consider rotation of ball joint.

Could anyone explain how to model this kind of ball joint, or give me some sources about this issue?